# Set Text in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android programming and so kingly pardon me if this question sounds stupid. I am developing a Calculator for Android. So I have around 20 buttons and a text field. Whenever a button is pressed I update the text field so that the user knows what he has typed.

However when I update the textfield the application is crashing.

updateExpression is the method that is called when any button is pressed.

```
  public void updateExpression (View v)
    {
      Log.d("string", "updateExpression Called");
      EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
      text.setText("HELLO EVERYONE");
    }
```

The .xml file of the buttons is:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:onClick="updateExpression"
    android:text="C" />
// goes on for 20 buttons with different ids and text

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:text="@string/edit_message" 
    android:layout_height="33dp" 
    android:textColor="@color/opaque_red"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally the logcat has the string data "updateExpression Called". However immediately after that it crashes. The error has tag AndroidRuntime Fatal Exception main. There are many more errors after this. A relevant one (according to me is)

Caused by: java.lang.classCatException: android.widget.TextView
cannot be cast into android.widget.EditText

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to cast a TextView into an EditText, like the error says. These are two **seperate** classes.

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

should be

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Comment: TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name); gives the error: TextView cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: control+shift+o to add your imports if your are using eclipse.

Comment: You need to import. Press ctrl + shift + O

Comment: Thanks a lot... I guess you are the one always answering my question! :)

Comment: I try to answer what I can :)

Answer (score 2):

In your xml its a `TextView`  In your code
 `EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);` 
Its a `EditText`. 
So choose one. This depends on your needs. If the user is able to type in this `View`, then use `EditText`. If its read-only and you will be handling these text, choose `TextView`.

Comment: I dont want to let the user use keypad to type in there. So I want to keep it TextView. But using "TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);" gives the error: TextView cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: control+shift+o to add your imports if your are using eclipse.